# How do I ask user to switch on the GPS of the device?

Tags: android, html, cordova, gps

I am working on an Cordova application using ionic.
I need user's coordinates for which I am using HTML5 geolocation API which does a graceful degradation if the best source isn't available. I have also added the cordova geolocation plugin that adds a global navigator object if not present. My app asks permission to use geolocation when I install the APK as well but it still gives me a location based on my network when my GPS is off.

I want to be able to ask user to switch on the GPS. How do I accomplish this. I am very new to HTML5 development for mobile.

Comment: Really? Is it still too broad ? I am just asking how do I make sure that I am taking geolocation only from GPS. I have already mentioned what I have done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you

https://github.com/mablack/cordova-diagnostic-plugin

I think the Geolocation API does not give you an error if the GPS is on/off, just a timeout error if it is not able to get a lock in the time limit you specify, but I tested it a while ago and I might be mistaking.